# Change div positioning on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am using override loosely.
I have a sticky header that changes to position:absolute after a certain scroll point.

```
var windw = this; $.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
var $this = this,
    $window = $(windw);

$window.scroll(function(e){
    if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
        $this.css({
            position: 'absolute',
            top: pos
        });
    } else {
        $this.css({
            position: 'fixed',
            top: 0
        });
    }
});};$('#header').followTo(352);
```

I have a div under the header that is revealed after the scroll point. I have an icon in that div that when click, i want to return the header to position: 'fixed'. I have tried a simple .click function but that does not work.

Extremely complicated fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/hadronian/9bUqr/

Comment: If you had a fiddle it would be much easier to debug [Fiddle Here](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: I would, but it is part of a much larger project

Comment: So make a sample thats much smaller

Comment: Your fiddle looks fine to me....? Is there something else you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Are you married to the followTo function? Or can we modify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for.  I'm sure there's some UI improvements you may be thinking about but if you want the header to show once another element is clicked this is what I came up with.

```
var windw = this;

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos, resetElement ) {
    var $this = this,
        $window = $(windw);
    var fixedCss = {
         position: 'fixed',
         top: 0
    };
    var absoluteCss = {
         position: 'absolute',
         top: pos
    };

    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            $this.css(absoluteCss);
        } else {
            $this.css(fixedCss);
        }
    });
    resetElement.click(function()
    {
        $this.css(fixedCss);
    });

};

$('#header').followTo(352, $('#down'));
```

Basically, pass a second jQuery element to the function (or perhaps just a selector) and bind on that object for when it's clicked to reset the CSS to a fixed position.

Like I said, there's probably more improvements you would like to do, to make the user experience a bit better, but hope this gets you on the right track.

http://jsfiddle.net/SfV3N/